# How to remove source code from browser in Next.js (CRA) app deployed on Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I'm developing a Next.js application (with create-react-app) and I want my code not to be seen in the browser (browser -> sources).

I set the environment variable GENERATE_SOURCEMAP = false and locally this solution works perfectly for me (dev and build).

When I deployed the application to Vercel hosting and set the environment variables, then that solution does not work, ie. my code is visible in the browser.

I think Vercel wraps all environment variables with "", so it's possible that this is causing the problem.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that you can never really hide Javascript code from the browser (it needs it to run it). You can at most expose obfuscated/minified code that's difficult to read, but it'll be there for a determined user to read.

Answer (score 2):

This problem happens when you want to upload the source map of your project for readable code in Sentry. I had this problem before and it was solved by using the **webpack-delete-sourcemaps-plugin** tool. add this code in  your `next.config.js` file:

```
const { DeleteSourceMapsPlugin } = require('webpack-delete-sourcemaps-plugin');


{
  // ...
  webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
    devtool: 'hidden-source-map', // optional, see the #hidden-source-map section for 
    config.plugins.push(new DeleteSourceMapsPlugin({ isServer, keepServerSourcemaps: true }))
    return config
  }
}
```

and if you use **react-app** in your `webpack.config.js` file add this lines:

```
module.exports = {
   devtool: 'hidden-source-map', // optional, see the #hidden-source-map section for more info
  // ...
  plugins: [
    new DeleteSourceMapsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because of Sentry. Just needed to add

sentry: { hideSourceMaps: true }

in next.config.js.